# closests jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="panels">
    <div>
        <h2>
        Test
        </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="inner_panel statict">
         Test2
    </div>
</div>
```

I want so that when people click on Test, Test2 appears. If not, they don't see Test2, How can I make that happen using jquery?

I tried the following but it does not work.

```
 $('.inner_panel').hide();

  $('.panels').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('div .inner_panel').toggle();
  });
```

I have multiple divs with class panels in the file, so I don't want click on Test affecting the other "panels."

Comment: I recommend using native `closest` like this `$(this.closest('div .inner_panel')).toggle()` it will increase code significantly (see here http://jsperf.com/jquery-closest-vs-element-closest)

Answer (score 1):

`closest` method looks up in the DOM tree, not down. You can check it here. http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Maybe you should use `.children('div.inner_panel')` to get your element. `children` method allows you to get elements, that are a single level down the DOM. Check http://api.jquery.com/children/ fo details.

Comment: I like how explained what's going on then provided an answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra space -> `$(this).closest('div .inner_panel').toggle();`

This should be: `$(this).closest('div.inner_panel').toggle();`

But `.closest()` is not going to work for you because it travels up the DOM tree and not up and then down to siblings etc.

I would do this:

```
$('.inner_panel').hide();

$('.panels').click(function () {
  $(this).find('div.inner_panel').toggle();
});
```

See [jsbin demo](http://jsbin.com/ihowok/1/edit)

Comment: Method `find` looks down to the end of the DOM, while `children` searches only in the children of current element, thus it should be faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('.inner_panel').hide();

 // Within .panels get the div's which contain an H2
 var containers = $('.panels h2').closest("div");

 // make them clickable
 containers.click(function () {
    // For the clicked panel, get the next element div which 
    // has the inner_panel class
    $(this).next('div.inner_panel').toggle();
 });
```

Comment: BTW, I would omit the first statement and just define the CSS for .inner_panel to have "display: none;"  Toggle will still make it visible.  Also, I separated out the "containers" selector as a variable for documentation purposes. You can just use the selector  in the click assignment and get rid of the variable.